# regarding memory used by chrome browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, jvm, applet

We have a web application which is downloading applets and running in chrome browser.

When we monitor the memory used by chrome in windows task manager it shows as 300 MB. Does this 300 MB include the jars which are downloaded for the applet running in chrome ?

Or is the  applet running inside the default browser jvm process ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, chrome uses that much RAM by default. However, regarding the applet situation, java will not be in-use since they dropped support for NPAPI architecture (Which corresponds to Java plugins) if you are using Google's chrome version 45 and above. 
Here are the full details: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml